# Parameter type definition in function of attribute Python

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, gherkin, python-behave

i am working as a TEA, i use Python + Selenium Webdriver and Behave to run my tests.

For this i define the webdriver inside the context as follows

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    context.driver = driver
    context.driver.get('https://www.ebay.com/')
```

This is defined in one function, but my problem is that when I want to use the driver in another step function i don't get the snippets for the the functions of driver. This makes me lose a lot of time looking what's the exact name of the function I am trying to use.

For example

```
@then('Click the "Search" button')
def step_impl(context: behave.runner.Context):
    """
    :type context: behave.runner.Context
    """
    search_btn = context.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gh-btn"]')
    search_btn.click()
```

I know I can define the type of the parameter received directly like

var_name: str `(def step_impl(context: behave.runner.Context)`, but the case I am looking for is more specific. like context.driver: 'webdriver object'

Is there a way to define the context.driver type so my ide will interpret that this is a webdriver object and in that way get the methods of the driver?

I am using PyCharm Professional

Comment: What have you tried? For example, did you try `def step_impl(context: behave.runner.Context):`?

Comment: Yes, but that will only give me access to the Context object functions, i am defining a parameter called context.driver that has a webdriver object

Comment: I don't know behave, but if it was properly typed, PyCharm would be able to figure out the type of `context.driver` from that.

Comment: The thing with context.driver is a property defined by me in another function, it is not built in property of behave.runner.Context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm should be able to work with this:

```
@then('Click the "Search" button')
def step_impl(context: behave.runner.Context):
    """
    :type context: behave.runner.Context
    """
    driver: webdriver.Chrome = context.driver
    search_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gh-btn"]')
    search_btn.click()
```

Comment: Could you give some details on what you do on the type declaration line? `driver: webdriver.Chrome = context.driver` Would like to understand this syntax. Thanks!

Comment: It's called a variable type annotation, it is introduced and described in detail in [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/)! They are used in [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), among other places.

Answer (score 0):

```
def step_impl(context: WebDriver):
    search_btn = context.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gh-btn"]')
    search_btn.click()
```

you don't have to define type two times.

The import you need:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
```